# Android - Listview not showing the last item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

My Problem is the last item in the listview is not displaying even though it has been added to the adapter and as well as in the list as i can see the number of items in the adapter is ok. Is it the problem with the layout? this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/golive_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Room"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Search1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Search" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/CreateRoomimageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/closed_doorplus" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listRooms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my class activity

```
public class chatRoomsListActivity extends Activity implements OnScrollListener  {

private static String Password;
private ListView lv;
private static Collection<HostedRoom> rooms;
private static ArrayList<String> Roomlist = new ArrayList<String>();
private static Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Button SearchButton;
private ImageButton CreateButton;
private EditText EditTextSearch;
private String Search;
private String RoomName;
private static ChatRoomListAdapter adapter;
private static String Nickname="";

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.chat_rooms);

            SearchButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Search1);
            CreateButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.CreateRoomimageButton);
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listRooms);        

            adapter = new ChatRoomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),  
R.layout.chat_rooms_wrapper);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            //ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins();

            try {
            populate_RoomList();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }     
          addListenerOnButton();


/*   
             arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                     this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Roomlist);            
             lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);   
             */


             lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parnet,    
android.view.View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                    setRoomName(ChatRoomListAdapter.getItemName(position));
                    showOptionDialog();

                    }
                });      
            addListenerOnButton();

        }

public void addListenerOnButton() {      
            final Context context = this;
                CreateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    createRoomDialog();                 
                }

            }); 

            SearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                     EditTextSearch=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Room);
                     Search=EditTextSearch.getText().toString();
                    //Search=Search.concat("*");

                         try {
                            // populate_RoomList();
                             getSearchlist();
                            // updateList();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }

            });
        }

public void getSearchlist() throws XMPPException{

        Roomlist.clear();
        adapter.clear();
        ChatRoomListAdapter.getChatRoom().clear();

        rooms=getHostedRooms(MyService.getConnection(),"conference."+  
MyService.getDomain());

              System.out.println("in getsearch");
            for (HostedRoom h : rooms)
            {
                System.out.println(h.getName().toString()+" contain " +Search);
                if(h.getName().toString().contains(Search)){
                System.out.println("roomlist= " +h.getJid().toString());

                Roomlist.add(h.getName());


System.out.println("ChatRooms.IsRoomPassProtected(h.getName())==   
"+ChatRooms.IsRoomPassProtected(h.getName()));

                if(ChatRooms.IsRoomPassProtected(h.getName())==true){
                    adapter.add(new ChatRoom(h.getName(),true));
                }
                else if(ChatRooms.IsRoomPassProtected(h.getName())==false){
                    adapter.add(new ChatRoom(h.getName(),false));
                 }

                  }
            }
            System.out.println("Adapter count="+adapter.getCount());
        }


private void populate_RoomList() throws XMPPException {

            //chatRoomsList.getRooms();"
            Roomlist.clear();
            adapter.clear();
            //rooms.clear();
            ChatRoomListAdapter.getChatRoom().clear();

            rooms=getHostedRooms(MyService.getConnection(),"conference."+  
MyService.getDomain());
            //System.out.println(rooms.iterator().next().getName());

            for (HostedRoom h : rooms)
            {
                System.out.println("roomlist= " +h.getName().toString());
                Roomlist.add(h.getName());

System.out.println("ChatRooms.IsRoomPassProtected(h.getName())==   
"+ChatRooms.IsRoomPassProtected(h.getName()));

                if(ChatRooms.IsRoomPassProtected(h.getName())==true){
                    adapter.add(new ChatRoom(h.getName(),true));
                }
                else if(ChatRooms.IsRoomPassProtected(h.getName())==false){
                    adapter.add(new ChatRoom(h.getName(),false));
                }

            }

            System.out.println("Adapter count="+adapter.getCount());

        }



public void setRoomName(String roomName) {
            RoomName = roomName;
        }

public static Collection<HostedRoom> getHostedRooms(Connection connection, String serviceName)
                throws XMPPException {
            List<HostedRoom> answer = new ArrayList<HostedRoom>();
            ServiceDiscoveryManager discoManager = new       
ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);
            DiscoverItems items = discoManager.discoverItems(serviceName);
            for (Iterator<DiscoverItems.Item> it = items.getItems(); it.hasNext();) {
                answer.add(new HostedRoom(it.next()));
            }
            return answer;
        }   

}
```

And this is my custom adapter

```
public class ChatRoomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChatRoom> {

private TextView name;
private static List<ChatRoom>  ChatRoom = new ArrayList<ChatRoom>();
private LinearLayout wrapper;
private ImageView lock;
public ChatRoomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}


public static List<ChatRoom> getChatRoom() {
    return ChatRoom;
}


public static void setChatRoom(List<ChatRoom> chatRoom) {
    ChatRoom = chatRoom;
}


public ChatRoom getItem(int index) {
    return ChatRoomListAdapter.ChatRoom.get(index);
}

public static String getItemName(int index) {
    return ChatRoomListAdapter.ChatRoom.get(index).name;
}


public static void setfriends(List<Friends> friends) {
    FriendListAdapter.setFriends(friends);
}

public void add(ChatRoom object) {
System.out.println("IN Chat room list adapter "+" addded");
ChatRoomListAdapter.ChatRoom.add(object);
    super.add(object);

}

public void remove(ChatRoom object) {
    ChatRoom.remove(object);
    super.remove(object);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     
this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_rooms_wrapper, parent, false);
    }

    wrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.C_R_wrapper);

    name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.C_R_RoomName);
    lock=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.C_R_Lock);

    try {
         Log.d("Chat room adapter", "heere");
         ChatRoom CR= getItem(position);
         System.out.println("name= "+CR.name);
         name.setText(CR.name);

            if(CR.lock==true)
            {
                lock.setImageResource(R.drawable.lock_lock_icon);
            }else{
                lock.setImageResource(R.drawable.lock_unlock_icon);
            }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   



return row;

}


public Bitmap decodeToBitmap(byte[] decodedByte) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}



}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to say without the code. Probably you did not call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your Viewpager

```
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

because the size you don't have at the bottom is exactly the size taken by your Toolbar

Example with RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_trips"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

Example with Viewpager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager_trip_history"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this you can solve your problem with this:

You just need to change your xml file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/golive_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Room"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:layout_weight="4">

        <requestFocus android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Search1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/CreateRoomimageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/closed_doorplus"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listRooms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">
        </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the second `LinearLayout` holding the `Listview` to `match_parent` height... It seems like your `LinearLayout` is growing with the `ListView` (`wrap_content`) out of your screen space

Comment: It would be better if you would just remove the linear layout surrounding the list view. It is useless.

Comment: @yekretsaM  i try to change it to match_parent still not showing one item.

Comment: @Barışcan Kayaoğlu i also try removing the liner layout surrounding the list view. but still no use.

Comment: i manage to show all items by specific a specific height but will it be compatible with all the android devices ? i set  android:layout_height="391dp" and its working

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last item inside getView of the Adapter and change it layout params height by setLayoutParams. But the minus is you have to correct other items height because the height will change when scroll the list up/down

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its very simple. Try to set the layout_height of your listview in the xml file to wrap_content.

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```